# Scanning images for a specific image, limiting range

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

So I have trouble understanding how to go by adjusting code that I found. Basically I want to look for an image inside an image (recognizing certain objects in photos my IP cam made). I found code online and this works except I want to look only in a certain area on the image. Currently the entire image is being scanned and I think that's unnecessary.

The code is as follows:

```
    unsafe
            {
                byte* pSmall = (byte*)(void*)HealthbarData.Scan0;
                byte* pBig = (byte*)(void*)CaptureData.Scan0;

                int smallOffset = HealthbarStride - HealthbarImage.Width * 3;
                int bigOffset = CaptureStride - CaptureImage.Width * 3;

                bool matchFound = true;

                for (int y = 0; y < CaptureHeight; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < CaptureWidth; x++)
                    {
                        byte* pBigBackup = pBig;
                        byte* pSmallBackup = pSmall;

                        //Look for the small picture.
                        for (int i = 0; i < HealthbarHeight; i++)
                        {
                            int j = 0;
                            matchFound = true;
                            for (j = 0; j < HealthbarWidth; j++)
                            {
                                //With tolerance: pSmall value should be between margins.
                                int inf = pBig[0] - Margin;
                                int sup = pBig[0] + Margin;
                                if (sup < pSmall[0] || inf > pSmall[0])
                                {
                                    matchFound = false;
                                    break;
                                }

                                pBig++;
                                pSmall++;
                            }

                            if (!matchFound)
                                break;

                            //We restore the pointers.
                            pSmall = pSmallBackup;
                            pBig = pBigBackup;

                            //Next rows of the small and big pictures.
                            pSmall += HealthbarStride * (1 + i);
                            pBig += CaptureStride * (1 + i);
                        }

                        //If match found, we return.
                        if (matchFound)
                        {
                            EnemyPosition.X = x;
                            EnemyPosition.Y = y;
                            break;
                        }
                        //If no match found, we restore the pointers and continue.
                        else
                        {
                            pBig = pBigBackup;
                            pSmall = pSmallBackup;
                            pBig += 3;
                        }
                    }

                    if (matchFound)
                        break;

                    pBig += bigOffset;
                }
            }
```

I can check under `if (matchFound)` to see if it's within the allowed range, but then it still scans the entire image.

Anyone who can give me any hints or how to do this? Let's say, it only checks within 300 pixels around the middle of the image.

Thank you.

Comment: If your capture data is stored as a bitmap you could crop your image first before traversing it

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1. Crop Original Image

Let's assume that your captured image `CaptureImage` is a `Bitmap`.

You could crop your `CaptureImage` before processing it.

```
Bitmap CaptureImage = MethodWhereImageDataComesFrom();

// you asked for ~300 pixels around the center, you can calculate that rectangle

int cropWidth = 300;
int cropHeight = 300;
int x = CaptureImage.Width / 2 - (cropWidth / 2);
int y = CaptureImage.Height / 2 - (cropHeight / 2);

// create your rectangle and bitmap of the cropped image bounds here
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, cropWidth, cropHeight);
Bitmap croppedImage = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);

// grab the graphics component of your cropped image so we can draw pixels from the capture image to it.
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(croppedImage);

// now draw the cropped pixels from capture
g.DrawImage(CaptureImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, croppedImage.Width, croppedImage.Height), rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

Now you can traverse `croppedImage` and it should only be a 300x300 pixel image.

Note this code is untested, although it should work.

## Option 2. Specify range in image loop

You should be able to specify your width and height range inside your image loop.

```
// define the dimensions we want to search in pixels
int cropWidth = 300;
int cropHeight = 300;

// determine our start positions for x and y (this is the top left corner of the rectangle we're searching in)
int startWidth = CaptureWidth / 2 - (cropWidth / 2); // start for x
int startHeight = CaptureHeight / 2 - (cropHeight / 2); // start for y
```

Now in your code where you begin your loop, you can simply specify the following:

```
for (int y = startHeight; y < startHeight + cropHeight; y++)
{
    for (int x = startWidth; x < startWidth + cropWidth; x++)
    {
        // your code here...
    }
}
```